# Including a typedef in two header files

Tags: c, include

I have this in ball.h:

```
#ifndef BALL_H_
#define BALL_H_
...
typedef void *PBALL  ;
...
#endif
```

in paddle.h I have:

```
#ifndef PADDLE_H_
#define PADDLE_H_
...
int contact_made(struct pppaddle*, PBALL);
...
#endif
```

I get an error in paddle.h because it doesn't know about PBALL.  So if I add:

```
#ifndef BALL_H_
#include    "ball.h"
#endif
```

to paddle.h (with or without the if statement) it works in my Cygwin environment.  But in Linux when I go to compile I get: "multiple definition of `newPBALL'" error on the source file that uses PBALL and also on the functions defined in ball.h.  How can I get paddle.h to understand PBALL without running into these problems in Linux?

My ball.c file:

```
struct newball {
    int x_pos, x_dir, y_pos, y_dir, y_delay, y_count, x_delay, x_count;
    char symbol;
};

typedef struct newball *ball_struct_ptr;
struct newball the_ball;

#include "ball.h"

PBALL newPBALL() {

    the_ball.y_pos = Y_INIT;
    the_ball.x_pos = X_INIT;
    the_ball.y_count = the_ball.y_delay = Y_DELAY;
    the_ball.x_count = the_ball.x_delay = X_DELAY;
    the_ball.y_dir = 1;
    the_ball.x_dir = 1;

    the_ball.symbol = DFL_SYMBOL;       //Set the symbol of the ball

    PBALL ptr = &the_ball;
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: I don't see `newPBALL` anywhere in your code snippets.  Please post a [complete, minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Also, as a tangential note, it's usually considered bad practice to hide pointers behind typedefs.

Comment: Also, you don't need another `#ifndef` around the `#include`.

Comment: I agree with Oli. Besides that, what else do you include? Is there maybe another include file with a similar typedef?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth as an even more tangential note, it's perfectly normal in Microsoft headers to typedef pointer names starting with P, so it could be that user994165 is just on a learning curve...

Comment: I think your problem is hidden in the code represented by the triple dots in the headers (that you aren't showing us), or in the C code that is using these headers (that you aren't showing us).  In other words, no-one can reliably help you because you've not given us enough information.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I added part of my ball.c.  All I'm importing there is ball.h.  ball.h is the only import I have from one header into another header.  All other imports I have are in the c files and the headers all check to make sure they haven't been imported before.  I tried taking out the import of ball.h into paddle.h and now the program doesn't compile using Cygwin in Windows but then in Linux it works!  I'm wondering if there's some way I can get it to work in both.  Also, about hiding the pointer, I'm doing that to make the program more object oriented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well instead of trying to import one header file into another (which worked in Cygwin but not Linux) or not importing the header into the other header (which worked for Linux but not Cygwin) I did this in both header files:

```
#ifndef TYPEDEF_PBALL_DECLARED_
#define TYPEDEF_PBALL_DECLARED_
typedef void *PBALL  ;
#endif
```

Now it's working in both environments.  I'll leave this open for a little while in case there is a better solution than having to declare typedef twice in two header files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what precisely is the problem, but I might be able to tell you how to figure it out.

Build your program as usual.  Capture the command line of the failing compilation step.  This might be something like:

```
gcc -c -o foo/bar.o baz.c
```

So baz.c presumably #includes the "bad" header files.  And you get the compilation error.  Now, track it down by just preprocessing your sources:

```
gcc -E -o foo/bar.c baz.c
```

-E being the option to stop after preprocessing, before actual compilation.  Now try to compile the preprocessed file:

```
gcc -c -o foo/bar.o bar.c
```

You should find a similar error as before.  Now look at the preprocessed source in bar.c from step 2 and you might easier find the cause.  Start with just searching for the identifier that the compiler is complaining about--is it in fact declared multiple times?  If so, why?  Could it be in another header?  Or perhaps there is a #define somewhere that is messing with your names?

Comment: should I be able to run the first command with all of my c files?  I get "cannot specify -o with -c or -S with multiple files"

Comment: Show us your build commands.  It is worrying that you are specifying multiple C files to build at once--perhaps you are building `ball.c` twice and linking them together by accident?